# EXE behaves differently when I place in start up folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a C# utility that monitors a database.  It's for my own use - I did not create an install package, but I did set the configuration to release.  I pulled the .exe out of the release folder, placed it on my desktop, double clicked it and it worked fine.

The next logical step was to place it in my Startup folder.  The result was unexpected.  Despite the code:

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InitializeControls();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

The form was never hidden.  On top of that VS 2010 started up as well.  Does anyone understand why the behavior is different when I place the .exe in the Startup folder v. just double click it?

Notes.  It connects to the database by pulling the connection string out of a config file:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ToString();
```

The only thing the config file contains is the connection string and I put the config file in the startup folder as well.  As far as what it does, it just queries the database and populates 7 or 8 labels on the form.  It minimizes to the system tray, runs every hour via a timer, but also has a refresh button.

Comment: It probably crashed and started a debugger it should not startup vs2010 for any other reason. Add information about how it connects to the database, where it keeps its user settings and how it works.

Comment: Add debug code to see if your EXE can access the config file. I think the whole `working directory` thing might be your problem

Comment: Thanks for reply, that makes sense. It was hard to tell if there was a crash because the form looked normal, but I'm sure you are correct.  I edited the initial post to provide more info, because my comment kept going over the word limit.  (This is my first post and I'm not used to the forum yet)  Could the issue be related to using a config file in the Startup folder?

Comment: Earlz, it does work under almost all conditions. I'm running it as we speak. The only time it crashed is when I put it in the Startup folder and reboot. When I just put the .exe and config file in the startup folder and double click the .exe, that also works. Only attempts to run it on startup fail. Do you think the startup folder can't be used with a config file?  Are you suggesting there is a way to add debug code such that when the exe crashes and VS opens, i can debug?  I've never done that.  I've only debugged from IDE.

Comment: ahh, yea I have no idea then. I'd just add something to print out the working directory on startup and make sure that you can access the config file from it.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you working dir is set incorrectly in startup filder link file. So app is missing *.exe.config file (or you just forgot to copy it?).

Comment: OK, how do I set the working directory?  I have the exe and config in Startup folder.  Should I add a vshost or one of the other files in the release folder as well?

Comment: Check the link file properties (via right click) look for 'working directory'. Other way, copy your exe and config to any dir (say C:\utils) and then right click drag exe to Startup folder of start menu and create a link, should work fine.

Comment: I did a right click on both the Start up folder and the exe itself, but I did not find 'working directory'. I actually like your second idea - that makes a lot of sense - I will try it on my next reboot. As long as that works, do you need me to mark your solution as accepted or anything like that?

Comment: You don't need to reboot a PC to test if startup link is working. Just navigate thru your start menu to 'Startup' and click your link to see if it's working. I can't say exact name of field in link properties dialog - my Windows is in Russian and maybe there are also differences between win versions too.

Comment: OK just rebooted, I tried the utils folder on C drive idea with the shortcut in the Startup folder and it still didn't work. It did not crash, but it did not move to system tray either. I had to kill it with the task manager. I think I will keep the utils folder and just start the app from a shortcut on the desktop. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Dez I am running into the same issue how did you get your application to work?